# mysql return true if user_id exists as met_user

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery

I am fairly new to MYSQl.  I am trying to create a query that will fit my needs.  I have developed an   [sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/771ebf/10)

Here is the story.  I have 5 tables. Users, Places, Meetings, Attend, and Met.

In the end, I would like to be able to choose places to view what meetings are held there.  I would like to view the attendees for each meeting.  I believe I can accomplish all that pretty easily.  but...

Here is where I am hung up.  I want to show a list of ALL users who are attending a meeting (actually, this should exclude my own id).  So one column should be user_names that list all users attending the meeting (excluding me) and another that lists who I have met shown as True or False or something similar.  So, All users from attend with specific meeting_id and True for all those from table met who have my user_id and their user_ids as met_user.

I can achieve many different elements of mysql.  I am struggling with this one.

Here is my schema

```
CREATE TABLE users (user_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                    user_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE places (place_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                     place_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE meetings (meeting_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                       place_id INT(6), 
                        meeting_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE attend (attend_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                     meeting_id INT(6), 
                     user_id INT(6));

CREATE TABLE met (met_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,   
                  meeting_id INT(6),
                  user_id INT(6),
                  met_user INT(6));

INSERT INTO users (user_name)
VALUES ('Jason'), ('Billy'), ('Sarah'), ('Julie'), ('Jennifer'), ('Laura') ;

INSERT INTO places (place_name)
VALUES ('London'), ('Paris'), ('New York'), ('Rome');

INSERT INTO meetings (place_id, meeting_name)
VALUES ('1', 'London Meeting #1'), ('1','London Meeting #2'), ('2','Paris Meeting'), ('3','New York Meeting'), ('4','Rome Meeting');

INSERT INTO attend (meeting_id, user_id)
VALUES ('1', '1'), ('2','1'), ('1','2'), ('1','3'), ('1','4'), ('1','5'), ('1','6');


INSERT INTO met (meeting_id, user_id, met_user)
VALUES ('1', '1', '2'), ('1', '1', '3'),('1', '1', '4'), ('1', '2', '1'), ('1', '2', '3'), ('1', '2', '4');
```

Here is one of the queries that I think might be closest.

```
Select u.*, at.meeting_id, at.user_id, m.meeting_name, met.*
from users as u
JOIN attend as at
ON at.user_id = u.user_id
JOIN meetings as m
ON at.meeting_id = m.meeting_id
LEFT JOIN met as met
ON met.user_id = at.user_id

Where m.meeting_id = 1
```

This query is showing All of my (I am Jason in this example) met_users, all of billy's met_users, and null for all other attendees (which is part of what I want).

```
**[Results][2]**:
| user_id | user_name | meeting_id | user_id |      meeting_name | met_id | meeting_id | user_id | met_user |
|---------|-----------|------------|---------|-------------------|--------|------------|---------|----------|
|       1 |     Jason |          1 |       1 | London Meeting #1 |      1 |          1 |       1 |        2 |
|       1 |     Jason |          1 |       1 | London Meeting #1 |      2 |          1 |       1 |        3 |
|       1 |     Jason |          1 |       1 | London Meeting #1 |      3 |          1 |       1 |        4 |
|       2 |     Billy |          1 |       2 | London Meeting #1 |      4 |          1 |       2 |        1 |
|       2 |     Billy |          1 |       2 | London Meeting #1 |      5 |          1 |       2 |        3 |
|       2 |     Billy |          1 |       2 | London Meeting #1 |      6 |          1 |       2 |        4 |
|       3 |     Sarah |          1 |       3 | London Meeting #1 | (null) |     (null) |  (null) |   (null) |
|       4 |     Julie |          1 |       4 | London Meeting #1 | (null) |     (null) |  (null) |   (null) |
|       5 |  Jennifer |          1 |       5 | London Meeting #1 | (null) |     (null) |  (null) |   (null) |
|       6 |     Laura |          1 |       6 | London Meeting #1 | (null) |     (null) |  (null) |   (null) |
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit @ollie Jones.  How did you do that? Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: OFF: You need enough reputation for do that.

Comment: Stack Overflow uses Markdown.  When you put code in a question, if you indent its lines by four spaces you get the code blocks. You can edit your own question without reputation.

Comment: Thanks!!!  That is incredibly helpful.

Comment: You are welcome. It's good to have you on Stack Overflow. You've done a good job presenting your question, with the sqlfiddle.

Comment: Now if only I can find an answer.  I have wasted probably 3 days trying to figure it out myself.  I am by no means a professional.

Comment: clarification: does the table `met` list the user ids that a particular single user (you) have met (or not) at each meeting? As far as I can see there's no way to say "billy met joey at London#1" in your schema.

Comment: If i were to "report" that I met someone I would add my user_id, meeting_id, and met_user (which is their user_id) to the met table.  If I were to log in as billy the report would then show who billy has met at which meeting. If the query works for my user_id then it should work if I change the user_id to Billy.  I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want to achieve something like this perhaps? (If not, could you post the query result you are expecting):

```
select u.user_id,u.user_name,
    case when exists (select * from met where met.user_id = 1 AND met.met_user = u.user_id) then 'true' else 'false' end didIMeet
from users as u join  attend as at 
    on u.user_id = at.user_id
    join meetings as m
    on at.meeting_id = at.meeting_id
where m.meeting_id = 1
    and u.user_id <> 1
```

Comment: Next I will need to list only those people who I have met and they have met (they have listed me in the met table and I have met them in the met table).  This will be a different question I am sure.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you, the next question also sounds achievable, give it a try, and seek for help as/if you need, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

one potential solution expanding your query:

```
Select u.*, at.meeting_id, at.user_id, m.meeting_name, met.*, case when met.met_id is null then 'no' else 'yes' end as met
from users as u
JOIN attend as at
ON at.user_id = u.user_id
JOIN meetings as m
ON at.meeting_id = m.meeting_id
LEFT JOIN met as met
ON (met.user_id = at.user_id and met.met_user = 1)

Where m.meeting_id = 1
AND u.user_id != 1
```

- filter your user_id out
- use your user_id as additional join condition in the left join
- use a case when conditional expression in the select to get 'yes' / 'no' instead of NULL or some numbers

A Problem with this approach is that your met table is not completely filled. For this to work you will need both entries for each pairing: (1 1 3) and (1 3 1), (1 1 4) and (1 4 1) etc. I think you will need the full pairing anyway as soon as you want to repeat the query for another user.